# React router isn't navigating

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a **signIn** and **signUp** in the nav bar.

My "/" path renders SignUp component and the SignUp component has a form with input and button.

On sumbitting the form or clicking the button I should be taken to ("/signin") SignIn page which renders my signIn component.

But, my **issue** is once i click button or sumbit the form it still stays in the ("/") signUp page and doesn't navigate to signIn page ("/signin")

***Code :***

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function Signup() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    <Redirect to="/signin" />;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label>
          Enter Mobile Number
        </label>
        <input />
        <button onClick={handleClick} >
          Get OTP
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Signup;
```

***App.js***

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

***Things I tried to fix this,***

I wrapped  in button :

```
<button onClick={handleClick} >
<Link to="/signin"> Get OTP </Link>
</button>
```

I also tried `onSumbit` in form instead of onClick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to compose in a `Link` element like:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
<Link to='/'>
  <button>
     Redirect to home
  </button>
</Link>
```

And for form, you can do like:

```
import { history } from "react-router-dom";
<form onSubmit={() => history.push("/")}>
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the button in Link:

```
<Link to='/'>
  <button>
     Redirect to home
  </button>
</Link>
```

and add Link component from 'react-router-dom':

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: Thanks, This works ! I will accept this answer. And what if i need to use the onSubmit on form instead of onClick of button? Wraping the whole form doesn't work i guess

Comment: In this case you can use history.push(path);

Comment: Using <Redirect /> works in that case ? @guilhermevictorramalhonatal

Comment: Yes works. but you will need a conditional to fire the redirect.

Comment: Quickly scribbled Redirect from home page to dashboard page: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-sunset-2hn7x?file=/src/App.js)